# Use part of a string in SQL declare statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, declare

I would like to make a query that gives the same result as the one shown below but where I only have to insert the first 4 digits in the SET statement i.e. "Set $campaignNo = '0029'" is there any way to fill in a wild card character in a string statement like that?

```
declare @campaignNo varchar(60)
set @campaignNo = '0029_old_Leu_2021_1'

Select Count(PUR1.intTimestamp) AS #start
From [MicrobialScreening].[dbo].[PUR_IDs] as ID 
INNER JOIN [MicrobialScreening].[dbo].[PUR_Purification1] AS PUR1 
   ON id.intID=pur1.intID
where id.strCampaign = @campaignNo
```

Comment: tag your database, is it microsoft sql server?

Comment: Depending on DB technology you can do LEFT or SUBSTRING on the value to parse out only what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe [LIKE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) is what you want:

```
declare @campaignNo varchar(60)
set @campaignNo = '0029'

Select Count(PUR1.intTimestamp) AS #start
From [MicrobialScreening].[dbo].[PUR_IDs] as ID 
INNER JOIN [MicrobialScreening].[dbo].[PUR_Purification1] AS PUR1 
   ON id.intID=pur1.intID
where id.strCampaign like @campaignNo+'%'
```

Answer (score 0):

If the campaign number is fixed width (first four as stated in the initial question), you can use the [LEFT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/left-transact-sql) function.

`set @campaignNo = '0029'`

...

`where LEFT(id.strCampaign, 4) = @campaignNo`

For more complicated parsing, you can use [SUBSTRING](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql) or [LIKE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql). If you are using an underscore to parse with [LIKE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql), make sure you use the [ESCAPE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql#pattern-matching-with-the-escape-clause) keyword to avoid ambiguity.

`where id.strCampaign = LIKE CONCAT(@campaignNo, '\_%') ESCAPE '\'`